# How to get a table of youtube channels, name and number of subscribers using python youtube data api

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I want to collect a list of youtube channels ordered by # of subscribers using youtube data api.
When I looked at the api, it looks like I can get get information on single channel only.

exmaple :

unbox therapy        16.5 millions 
 linus tech tips      10   millions

example of using the api:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
youtube = build(api_service_name ,api_version, developerKey=api_key)
youtube.search().list(q = "unbox therapy", part = "id, snippet", maxResults = 2).execute()
```

thanks
joseph

Comment: Why not get your list of channels, then sort it?

Comment: @Sri I don't know how to query to get all channels. only a specific one.

Comment: Yes, query each channel individually. Store them in a list. Sort the list by your value.

Comment: but in order to query each channel I need to know its id/name
I don't have them , that is the big problem.I need to get the list of all channels.

Comment: list of ALL youtube channels?

Comment: yes exactly. once I have them , I can look at each channel and extract whatever info I need.

Comment: I do not think such an API exists to get a list of ALL youtube channels. You could perhaps scrape a page like SocialBlade to get the top 100 most subscribed channels, but the API call you are expecting would return over 31 million results.

Comment: thanks @Sri I think that you are right.I'll see if the site has an api.